# Change the colors of polygons on a choropleth map with leaflet

Tags: polygon, leaflet, data, web-mapping, features

I have data from different countries (=polygons) from 1990 to 2012 and depending on the data value I want to map the changes with a timeline enabling the user to visualize the changes (with colors) from 1990 all the way to 2012.

I am using leaflet for the first time, so a little more detailed answer would be great.

---

I got the shapefile to show on the map, but when I try to the style function it doesn't work (no colors). the column "greenhousegaz_1990" contains the data I want to show.

I tried with the ID column just to test and it worked fine, colors did show correctly and in range.

```
function getColor(d) {
    return
           d > 900000  ? '#762A83' :
           d > 750000  ? '#af8dc3' :
           d > 600000  ? '#e7d4e8' :
           d > 450000  ? '#f7f7f7' :
           d > 300000  ? '#d9f0d3' :
           d > 150000  ? '#7fbf7b' :
                         '#1B7837';
}



function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.greenhousegaz_1990),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the tutorial setup by leaflet [Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). It is very detailed and provides a step-by-step instructions.

You could follow along and would need to have a countries features in GeoJSON data which would allow for easy interaction with this tutorial.

Here is the example map [interactively](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. now I have a problem with my data column.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your data column? I'm interested in the values and column property. Also, make sure the data column you are interested in displaying is being input as a parameter. e.g.us-states.js

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dYY8p  the data was in an csv file, and I did a joint with the continent shapefile based on countries codes. I'm guessing the spacing is causing the problem.

Comment: That might be the issue, keep in mind, the tutorial has place the data in GeoJSON data format.

Comment: I removed the spaces from the column title, the data is in GeoJSON, the input parameters are correct as I tested with the ID column to make sure. any idea where is the problem ?

Comment: Did you update your input parameters after the test? Perhaps you kept a data column name or parameter instead of switching to the data column name of interest? I'm thinking it is a minor find for you to resolve, its a bit difficult to guess without seeing what you are seeing right now in terms of your GeoJSON data setup and input in leaflet. Be sure that you are entering/referring to the correct column name: greenhousegaz_1990 [YR 1990]

Comment: It works perfectly I forgot to add a comma. Is there a possibility to add a timeline control to enable the user to change the year ? (different data column for each year). I found a Leaflet.Timeline plugin should I just understand and edit the code in my html file ? thank you for your help.

Comment: It should work. I would say if you run into issues with the time line. Close this question as answered and ask a another question for the time line per GIS SE rules. I'll be happily to try to assist again.