# Leaflet combination chloropleth and Leaflet.TimeDimension

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, leaflet-plugins

Following up the post  from [Change the colors of polygons on a choropleth map with leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256905/change-the-colors-of-polygons-on-a-choropleth-map-with-leaflet/339556#339556)
I'm wondering if it is possible to combine a Leaflet chloropleth with the Leaflet.TimeDimension so that the there is a slider where the user can control the years and the colors on the map change correspondingly.

To the background: Lines connect a building with a levee failure of a river (or we could say two imaginary points). With time, the water depth of the flooded building changes. I'd like to show that based on the color of the line (connecting the levee failure with the building). Therefore, moving the time slider should result in a change of the line color.

I have 114 time steps, each lying 20min apart. The date where they start was chosen randomly.
So far, so good. After some try-and-errors I (might have) figured out a way how to represent the lines correctly with the corresponding times.

Two problems still remain:

1. By removing all the coordinates between the starting and end point of the line I could prevent the line from beeing gradually build over the time. But it still only shows after the second time step. What can I do that it is visible from the start?
2. In the function `teststyle(feature)` I tried to retrieve the current water depth of the line at the current time step, but I didn't have luck to do so so far. The line `color: setColor(feature.properties.CurrentTime)` should look in the GeoJSON for the corresponding property and color the line (e.g. water depth) as defined in the function `setColor(f)`. The colors chosen herefore are random up to now.

The html-file looks as follows:

```
var map = L.map('map',{preferCanvas: true}).setView([46.7252, 8.1909], 14);
var timeDimension = new L.TimeDimension({
        period: "P0Y0M0DT0H20M0S"

    });
timeDimensionOptions:
    CurrentTime: new Date ("2019-10-22").getTime()
map.timeDimension = timeDimension; 


var player = new L.TimeDimension.Player(
      {
        transitionTime: 100,
        loop: false,
        startOver: false
      },
      timeDimension
    );

var timeDimensionControlOptions = {
    player: player,
    timeDimension: timeDimension,
    playReverseButton : true,
    position: "bottomleft",
    autoPlay: false,
    minSpeed: 1,
    speedStep: 0.5,
    maxSpeed: 15,
    stimeSliderDragUpdate: true
    };

var timeDimensionControl = new L.Control.TimeDimension(timeDimensionControlOptions);

map.addControl(timeDimensionControl);

function setColor(f) {
    return f > 3 ? '#fef0d9':
        f > 2  ? '#b30000':
        f > 1.5  ? '#e34a33':
        f > 1  ? '#fc8d59':
        f > 0.8   ? '#fdbb84':
        f > 0.6   ? '#fdd49e':
        f > 0.4   ? '#a6bddb' :
        f > 0.2   ? '#2b8cbe' :
              '#fef0d9';
    }

function teststyle(feature) {
    return {
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: setColor(feature.properties.CurrentTime),
      dashArray: '',
      fillOpacity: 1,
    };
  }

 var timeSeriesLayer=L.geoJSON(Lines_LV1, {style: teststyle})

 var geojson = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(timeSeriesLayer);

 geojson.addTo(map);

 var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

 legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 3],
        labels = ['Values in m water depth per building'],
        from, to;

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        from = grades[i];
        to = grades[i + 1];

        labels.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
    }

    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
    return div;
    };

 legend.addTo(map);
```

and finally the geojson I'm trying to implement looks like this (subsequent code is one line feature of total 444 features):

```
var Lines_LV1 = {
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "id" : 0,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "LineString",
        "coordinates" : [
          [
            8.1872821807176006,
            46.722675259950208
          ],
          [
            8.0497022008185972,
            46.749807786672605
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "FID" : 0,
        "times": [
        "2019-10-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T00:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T00:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T01:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T01:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T01:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T02:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T02:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T02:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T03:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T03:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T03:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T04:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T04:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T05:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T05:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T05:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T06:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T06:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T06:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T07:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T07:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T07:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T08:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T08:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T08:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T09:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T09:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T09:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T10:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T10:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T10:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T11:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T11:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T11:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T12:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T12:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T12:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T13:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T13:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T13:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T14:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T14:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T14:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T15:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T15:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T15:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T16:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T16:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T16:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T17:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T17:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T17:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T18:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T18:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T18:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T19:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T19:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T19:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T20:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T20:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T20:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T21:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T21:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T21:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T22:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T22:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T22:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T23:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T23:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-22T23:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T00:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T00:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T00:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T01:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T01:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T01:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T02:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T02:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T02:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T03:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T03:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T03:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T04:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T04:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T04:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T05:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T05:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T05:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T06:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T06:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T06:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T07:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T07:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T07:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T08:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T08:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T08:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T09:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T09:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T09:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T10:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T10:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T10:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T11:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T11:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T11:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T12:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T12:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T12:40:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T13:00:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T13:20:00.000Z",
        "2019-10-23T13:40:00.000Z"
        ],
        "V25OBJECTI" : 12349778,
        "X_centroid" : 646692,
        "Y_centroid" : 177806,
        "X_levee" : 657233,
        "Y_levee" : 174881,
        "OBJECTID" : 1,
        "V25OBJEC_1" : 12349778,
        "Wert" : 1103346,
        "X_centro_1" : 646692,
        "Y_centro_1" : 177806,
        "Node_ID_10" : 0,
        "Node_ID_11" : 0,
        "Node_ID_12" : 0,
        "Node_ID_13" : 0,
        "Node_ID_14" : 0,
        "Node_ID_15" : 0,
        "Node_ID_1" : 41,
        "Node_ID_2" : 0,
        "Node_ID_3" : 0,
        "Node_ID_4" : 0,
        "Node_ID_5" : 0,
        "Node_ID_6" : 0,
        "Node_ID_7" : 0,
        "Node_ID_8" : 0,
        "Node_ID_9" : 0,
        "MaxDepth" : 0.50578500000000004,
        "2019-10-22T00:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T00:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T00:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T01:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T01:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T01:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T02:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T02:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T02:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T03:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T03:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T03:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T04:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T04:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T05:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T05:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T05:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T06:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T06:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T06:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T07:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T07:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T07:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T08:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T08:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T08:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T09:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T09:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T09:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T10:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T10:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T10:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T11:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T11:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T11:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T12:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T12:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T12:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T13:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T13:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T13:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T14:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T14:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T14:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T15:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T15:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T15:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T16:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T16:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T16:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T17:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T17:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T17:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T18:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T18:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T18:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T19:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T19:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T19:40:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T20:00:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T20:20:00.000Z" : 0,
        "2019-10-22T20:40:00.000Z" : 0.272548999999999,
        "2019-10-22T21:00:00.000Z" : 0.288399999999999,
        "2019-10-22T21:20:00.000Z" : 0.303223,
        "2019-10-22T21:40:00.000Z" : 0.317962,
        "2019-10-22T22:00:00.000Z" : 0.332637,
        "2019-10-22T22:20:00.000Z" : 0.344395999999999,
        "2019-10-22T22:40:00.000Z" : 0.356130999999999,
        "2019-10-22T23:00:00.000Z" : 0.367991,
        "2019-10-22T23:20:00.000Z" : 0.377790999999999,
        "2019-10-22T23:40:00.000Z" : 0.387606,
        "2019-10-23T00:00:00.000Z" : 0.397473,
        "2019-10-23T00:20:00.000Z" : 0.405696999999999,
        "2019-10-23T00:40:00.000Z" : 0.413768,
        "2019-10-23T01:00:00.000Z" : 0.421794,
        "2019-10-23T01:20:00.000Z" : 0.429505,
        "2019-10-23T01:40:00.000Z" : 0.437203999999999,
        "2019-10-23T02:00:00.000Z" : 0.444894,
        "2019-10-23T02:20:00.000Z" : 0.450585999999999,
        "2019-10-23T02:40:00.000Z" : 0.456243,
        "2019-10-23T03:00:00.000Z" : 0.461880999999999,
        "2019-10-23T03:20:00.000Z" : 0.466127999999999,
        "2019-10-23T03:40:00.000Z" : 0.470318999999999,
        "2019-10-23T04:00:00.000Z" : 0.474488,
        "2019-10-23T04:20:00.000Z" : 0.478107,
        "2019-10-23T04:40:00.000Z" : 0.480688999999999,
        "2019-10-23T05:00:00.000Z" : 0.484501,
        "2019-10-23T05:20:00.000Z" : 0.486929,
        "2019-10-23T05:40:00.000Z" : 0.489207,
        "2019-10-23T06:00:00.000Z" : 0.491551999999999,
        "2019-10-23T06:20:00.000Z" : 0.493885999999999,
        "2019-10-23T06:40:00.000Z" : 0.496225,
        "2019-10-23T07:00:00.000Z" : 0.498570999999999,
        "2019-10-23T07:20:00.000Z" : 0.500241,
        "2019-10-23T07:40:00.000Z" : 0.502043,
        "2019-10-23T08:00:00.000Z" : 0.503745,
        "2019-10-23T08:20:00.000Z" : 0.504449999999999,
        "2019-10-23T08:40:00.000Z" : 0.505117999999999,
        "2019-10-23T09:00:00.000Z" : 0.505785,
        "2019-10-23T09:20:00.000Z" : 0.505487,
        "2019-10-23T09:40:00.000Z" : 0.505153999999999,
        "2019-10-23T10:00:00.000Z" : 0.50482,
        "2019-10-23T10:20:00.000Z" : 0.503843,
        "2019-10-23T10:40:00.000Z" : 0.502842,
        "2019-10-23T11:00:00.000Z" : 0.501839999999999,
        "2019-10-23T11:20:00.000Z" : 0.500148,
        "2019-10-23T11:40:00.000Z" : 0.498477999999999,
        "2019-10-23T12:00:00.000Z" : 0.496809999999999,
        "2019-10-23T12:20:00.000Z" : 0.494811999999999,
        "2019-10-23T12:40:00.000Z" : 0.49281,
        "2019-10-23T13:00:00.000Z" : 0.490806999999999,
        "2019-10-23T13:20:00.000Z" : 0.488804999999999,
        "2019-10-23T13:40:00.000Z" : 0.486802999999999,
        "X_levee_1" : 657233,
        "Y_levee_1" : 174881
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks fore the reply. How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I know of no such example. You'll have to learn Leaflet and it's plugins enough to try it yourself. If you get stuck in the process, then you can get help here.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: Hi TomazicM,
sorry the text went off too quickly. I edited the question above.
I'm happy to clarify unclear parts of the code.

Comment: Please add also explanation of how these time series should look like/behave. What is the role of the following properties in time series: `coordinates` array, `properties.time` array, `TS_nnnn` properties and/or any other properties that are used in time series. You are also using `feature.properties.insol` property in your GeoJSON style, but I don't see any such property in your GeoJSON sample.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear formulation; I edited the question and hope it is clearer now. The `coordinates` in the geojson are the first and last point of the line. `feature.properties.insol` was copied from an example off the internet, I corrected that. `TS_nn` represented TimeStep_nn in seconds. However, I realized I have to change the time format. 'properties.time' was an try to get the water depth of the current time, I changed that and clearified it in the Question Nr. 2.

Comment: I assume from your comments that you do not have GeoJSON with predefined form of properties, that you can construct them as it suites you. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I create the GeoJSON in Python and I'm free which properties I'd like to add to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.TimeDimension.Layer.GeoJSON` layer of [L.TimeDimension](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension) plugin support two kinds of GeoJSON time series:

- If geometry/feature is LineString and there is an array of times associated with it, it must have as many items as coordinates in the LineString. Time travel in this case means progressively adding points that correspond to time.
- Otherwise time travel means that at given time those features are displayed that have this time included in the properties.

In your case you have LineString features with multiple times, but don't want to display line strings progressively from poin to point. Solution with `L.TimeDimension` plugin would be to repeat each feature several times (once for every time) with same geometry but different properties. This would be misuse of resources if LineStrings would consists of several hundreds of points each.

Much simpler and more flexible solution in this case is to write one's own simple time slider, tailored for this particular case. Range `input` HTML element is used for slider and `setStyle` layer method is used to dynamically change feature style.

Since what changes with time is just one value, time series can be defined as a feature property which contains an array of `[time, value]` pairs. For simplicity the example below presupposes that each feature contains same number of same times. Working JSFiddle example is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/myesfdnh/

```
<div id='map'>
  <div id="sliderContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; background-color: white; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 5000">
    <input type="range" id="timeSlider" min="1" max="11" value="1" style="float: left; padding: 6px;" oninput="updateTime(this.value);" onchange="updateTime(this.value);">
    <div id="currentTime" style="float: left; padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 6px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
.
.
.
var myGeojson = [
  {"type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {"type":"Feature",
          "id":1,
          "properties":{
            "name":"F001",
            "timeSeries":[
              ["2019-10-23T08:20:00.000Z", 0.1],
              ["2019-10-23T08:40:00.000Z", 0.3],
              ["2019-10-23T09:00:00.000Z", 0.4],
              ["2019-10-23T09:20:00.000Z", 0.8],
              ["2019-10-23T09:40:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T10:00:00.000Z", 0.8],
              ["2019-10-23T10:20:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T10:40:00.000Z", 1.5],
              ["2019-10-23T11:00:00.000Z", 2],
              ["2019-10-23T11:20:00.000Z", 3],
              ["2019-10-23T11:40:00.000Z", 2.5]
            ]
          },
          "geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-100.231018,47.875829],[-100.231018,47.875829],[-100.225525,47.715306],[-100.225525,47.715306],[-100.057983,47.717154],[-100.057983,47.717154],[-100.063477,47.885039],[-100.063477,47.885039]]}
        },
        {"type":"Feature",
          "id":2,
          "properties":{
            "name":"F002",
            "timeSeries":[
              ["2019-10-23T08:20:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T08:40:00.000Z", 0.8],
              ["2019-10-23T09:00:00.000Z", 0.3],
              ["2019-10-23T09:20:00.000Z", 0.1],
              ["2019-10-23T09:40:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T10:00:00.000Z", 1.8],
              ["2019-10-23T10:20:00.000Z", 2.1],
              ["2019-10-23T10:40:00.000Z", 3],
              ["2019-10-23T11:00:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T11:20:00.000Z", 2],
              ["2019-10-23T11:40:00.000Z", 1.5]
            ]
          },
        "geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-100.310669,47.648737],[-100.310669,47.648737],[-99.931641,47.656138],[-99.931641,47.656138]]}
        },
        {"type":"Feature",
          "id":3,
          "properties":{
            "name":"F003",
            "timeSeries":[
              ["2019-10-23T08:20:00.000Z", 0.8],
              ["2019-10-23T08:40:00.000Z", 0.7],
              ["2019-10-23T09:00:00.000Z", 0.1],
              ["2019-10-23T09:20:00.000Z", 0.5],
              ["2019-10-23T09:40:00.000Z", 2],
              ["2019-10-23T10:00:00.000Z", 1.5],
              ["2019-10-23T10:20:00.000Z", 1],
              ["2019-10-23T10:40:00.000Z", 1.5],
              ["2019-10-23T11:00:00.000Z", 0.8],
              ["2019-10-23T11:20:00.000Z", 0.1],
              ["2019-10-23T11:40:00.000Z", 0.5]
            ]
          },
        "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-99.989319,47.829752],[-99.989319,47.964181],[-99.780579,47.964181],[-99.780579,47.829752],[-99.989319,47.829752]]]}
        }
    ]
  }
];

var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var timeIndex = 0;
var times = [];

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.id == 1) { 
    feature.properties.timeSeries.forEach(function (value, index) {
      times.push(value[0]);
    });
    var timeSlider = document.getElementById('timeSlider');
    timeSlider.setAttribute('min', '1');
    timeSlider.setAttribute('max', (times.length - 1));
  }
}

function setColor(f) {
  return f > 3   ? '#fef0d9':
         f > 2   ? '#b30000':
         f > 1.5 ? '#e34a33':
         f > 1   ? '#fc8d59':
         f > 0.8 ? '#fdbb84':
         f > 0.6 ? '#fdd49e':
         f > 0.4 ? '#a6bddb' :
         f > 0.2 ? '#2b8cbe' :
                   '#fef0d9';
}

function setStyle(feature) {
  return {
      weight: 4,
      opacity: 1,
      color: setColor(feature.properties.timeSeries[timeIndex][1]),
      fillColor: '#3388ff',
      fillOpacity: 0.2
  };
};

var  myLayer = L.geoJSON(myGeojson, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  style: setStyle
}).addTo(map);

function updateTime(index) {
  var time;

  timeIndex = index - 1;
  myLayer.setStyle(setStyle);
  time = times[timeIndex];
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = time.slice(0, 10) + ' ' + time.slice(11, 16);
};

var sliderContainer = document.getElementById('sliderContainer');
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(sliderContainer);
L.DomEvent.on(sliderContainer, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop);

map.fitBounds(myLayer.getBounds());
updateTime(1);
```